# Large Graph is cropping from bottom in the overview Component in Yfiles

Tags: graph, yfiles

I am using Yfiles to to show the overview of the large Graph on the top left of the window. If the Graph is too big it is being cropped from the bottom in the overview div element. Any suggestions how we prevent the cropping of large graph from the overview component.

Answer (score 1):

This indicates that either your [content rectangle](https://docs.yworks.com/yfileshtml/#/dguide/view_graphcontrol#view_graphcontrol_managing-the-view) is not up to date (the overview always uses the `contentRect` to determine the bounds of the visible region in the overview), or your graph is *that* large that the [`minimumZoom`](https://docs.yworks.com/yfileshtml/#/api/CanvasComponent#CanvasComponent-property-minimumZoom) property prevents the *overview* from not showing all contents: The default value is `0.0001`, the enforced minimum `0.0000001`, so you can try smaller values if your graph is really millions of units wide/high.